# Unable to save Paypal sandbox webhook url

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

We are configuring Paypal Sandbox webhook and getting an error. We have tested the URL using RestClient and it is hitting our test servers. See attached.

[image: PayPal Sandbox Webhook Setup]

We tried live and it does saves our webhook url.